# Javascript / Jquery: get index of char within element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple way to get the index of a char within an element? For example, if I'm looking at the first span below, then I want to know that its first char is the seventh char within the li. I will only need to know this for chars within an element (no textnodes), but there may be textnodes, and their chars do "count".

```
<li id = "li">
    <p>0123</p>
    <div>4
      <span id = "span">5</span>
      <span>67</span>
    </div>
    8
</li>
```

Edit: Added IDs to the elements above. then something like:

```
index = getIndexOfFirstChar($("#span"), $("#li"))
```

Note that the chars are not unique. I used numbers, but it could be any text.

Comment: So you need also to ignore all the whitespaces, I guess?

Comment: var text = document.querySelector('li').innerText;
text.length; /*count*/
text.charAt(0); /*symbol*/

Comment: @VitVad `innerText` is not a standardized property. I wouldn't suggest to use it.

Comment: Hmm, actually, it probably should include the whitespaces. The real data has whitespace:pre so they do count. For the example above, it means that the html should be written without the extra spaces.

Comment: @VisioN, here is crossbrowser sollution for innerText - http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.text

Comment: @VitVad, This won't give me what I need. What I have is the span and the li.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a mix of `.text()` (to get inner text without HTML), `.replace()` (to remove whitespace) and `.indexOf()` to get the index:

```
var clearTextWithNoWhitespace = $('li').text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
var index = clearTextWithNoWhitespace.indexOf('5');

console.log(clearTextWithNoWhitespace); //012345678
console.log(index); //5
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YAfSV/)

If you want to include whitespace:

```
var index = $('li').text().indexOf('5');
console.log(index); //22
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YAfSV/1/)

Comment: What if there is more than one "5"?

Comment: @user984003 Then how do you need to specify the concrete `5`?

Comment: How? That's what I'm asking. I've got the span in my hand. Now I want to know the index of its first char in relation to all the text within the li. Why? That's what I need!